# Calculating the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln [n(\ln \ln n)^p]}.$

Tags: limits

I calculated the following limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln [n(\ln \ln n)^p]}=0.$$ Could the fixed real number $p$ cause problems in the calculation of this limit? If for example we have $p=0$ then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln n + pn\ln \ln n}$$ and I would find an indeterminate form at the denominator $p\times\infty=0\times\infty$.

Or $p$ is just a real number and the form I obtain can't be defined as an indeterminate form? What about if $p<0$?

Comment: if p = 0 then why keep that part in the denominator in the first place? I dont see how this could be an issue in this case.

Comment: @Jakob $n\ln \ln n \to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. If $p=0$ we just delete the part of the denominator that $p$ multiplies. So $p\times\infty$ can not be an indeterminate form. Am I right?

Comment: @Jakob Why isn't $p\times\infty$ an indeterminate form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write:
$$n\ln[n(\ln\ln n)^p]=n\ln n - np\ln\ln\ln n$$
You can show that this goes to $+\infty$ for $n\to\infty$, thus your limit goes to $0$.